# Seek and compute total number of records in SAS7BDAT file from Python exclusively with open source tools

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I have some sas7dat files that contains hundreds of millions of rows and are in the neighborhood of 100GB - 1000GB. I would like to be able to do the following efficiently:

1. Compute the number of records in the file.
2. Seek to record *n*.

Is there any way to do this with the `pandas.read_sas` interface? I would like to avoid using SAS itself.

Comment: In SAS it would be a libname statement and a quick SQL query - no need to read the files again. But this likely means its also in the file metadata somewhere, its just an issue of how to access the information. I don't have enough skills to solve this, but I would suggest seeing Chris Hemedinger blog and posts about access SAS data sets with other tools.  SAS is trying to work better with python as well. The solution in SAS is 4 lines of code, let me know if you want that.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the SAS solution is 4 lines of code. I need a python solution, though, as we are not using SAS. We have legacy data in SAS.

Comment: What we know about the .sas7dat file format: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/vignettes/sas7bdat.pdf

Comment: So one of those unknown are probably what you need. Another option then, SAS Universal Viewer is free and can access SAS data sets, it should be able to get you that information if this is a one time task, if not, a different solution is needed.

Comment: Yes, I can use the SAS Universal Viewer https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=712, but it doesn't run on my Mac...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! But the answer involves not using pandas, which is why I changed the title.

There is an [open source SAS7BDAT implementation for Apache Spark](https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat). (It's written in Scala). "This format is splittable when input is uncompressed thus can achieve high parallelism for a large SAS file.... Thanks to the splittable SasInputFormat, we are able to convert a 200GB (1.5Bn rows) .sas7bdat file to .csv files using 2000 executors in under 2 minutes."

With this code, the efficient way to count the number of lines would be:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load("input.sas7bdat")
print("Number of rows in input.sas7bdat: {}".format(df.count()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file and use .shape to determine the number of rows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sas('filename.sas7bdat')
df.shape[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not efficient, as it requires the entire file to be read. My file won't fit in RAM; my file is 100GB to 1000GB in size. I don't have a machine with 2-5 TB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to *efficiently* read the file and do what you want to do with `pandas`. Here is a way out -

Use the `chunksize` parameter to your advantage -

```
CHUNKSIZE = 1e6
rows = 0
for df in pd.read_sas('path/to/sas/filename.sas7bdat', chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, iterator=True):
    rows += df.shape[0]
    # whatever else you want
```

**Explanation**

This reads a million rows at a time (vary the `chunksize` depending upon how much RAM you can afford) and iteratively counts what you want. Alternatively you can use it to do other `df` related operations as well, as long as you keep accumulating them.

**Warning**

On commodity hardware trying to read ~100s of GBs, still going to be inefficient.